# Where to save and fetch user group data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While implementing user groups, when the users join a group and when they relaunch the app they're still in the group. My question is that when the users launch and need to retrieve what group they're in and who else is in it. Here are two options that I'm undecided which one to go for.

1. Loop through the "groups" node (contains groupIDs and a list of users in each group) every time user launch the app.
2. When user join a group, store the necessary data of that group under "users/$uid/group" node so when they launch the app, they don't have to fetch the data from "groups" node every time.

From my understanding, option 1 requires fetching the entire "groups" node and save some storage space while option 2 needs less data fetching since the group info is already in its user's node but this sacrifice more storage space since many users in the same group will store the same group info under each user's node. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only save the group ID's that the user has joined under its /$uid/Groups
And when logging in, fetch the list of users for only these groups from the main Groups node.

You will need to fetch the data every time the user log in as users might change over time

Comment: Right. I haven't thought through how the users under user/group/ get updated. That makes it clear. Thanks